# PHP5 Class Property Overloading w/ Dependency Container

Tags: php, oop, reference, dependencies, overloading

----------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------------------

I didn't explain very well what I am ultimately trying to accomplish with this overloading.    I basically just want to use the config object to store everything and only have one instance spawned of the database, also in config.   Then when I load the page, I want to bootstrap things like session data, user details, application state,  various ID's, etc.. etc..   by just adding an array to config object like :

```
$userSession['ctime'] = time();
$userSession['key'] = rndkey(32);
etc... etc...
```

Then use the config object like ...

```
$_config = new configObject();
$_config->__set('SESSION', $userSession);
etc.. etc...
```

Hope that helps make a little more sense as to what I'm trying to figure out.

----------------------END UPDATE------------------------------------------

Can I overload a dependency containers static config property?   I want to adjust my code to have the object set dynamic config values but I don't really want to spend all the time changing it around if it's not going to work.  I read something about you can't __set() by reference, and not sure how that relates to a static property.

Example...   (These classes are obviously stripped down and simplified)

```
class depCon {

    public static $_database;
    public static $_config;

    //Database Dependencies
    public static function createDatabaseObject() {

        $db = new mysqliObject();
        $db->setConfig(self::$_config);
        $db->connect();

        return $db;
    }
}


class configObject {

    public $overload = array();

    public function __construct() {

        //set some default values

        $this->__set('DBHOST', 'localhost');
        $this->__set('DBUSER', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
        $this->__set('DBNAME', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
        $this->__set('DBPASS', 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
    }

    public function __get($item) { 
        return array_key_exists($item, $this->overload) ?
            $this->overload[$item] : false;
    }

    public function __set($item, $value) { 
        $this->overload[$item] = $value; 
    }

}  

class mysqliObject {

    public $user = "";
    public $pass = "";          
    public $name = "";
    public $host = "";

    public $_db;
    public $_config;


    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function __destruct() {

        $this->close();
    }

    public function connect() {

        $this->host = $this->_config->get('DBHOST');
        $this->name = $this->_config->get('DBNAME');
        $this->user = $this->_config->get('DBUSER');
        $this->pass = $this->_config->get('DBPASS');
        $this->MYSQLI_LINK = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->name);
    }

    public function setDatabase($databaseConnection) {

        $this->_db = $databaseConnection;
    }

    public function setConfig($config) {

        $this->_config = $config;
    }

    public function close() {

        @mysqli_close($this->MYSQLI_LINK);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$_config = new configObject();
depCon::$_config = $_config;
$dbi = depCon::createDatabaseObject();
depCon::$_database = $dbi;
```

So the question is,  if I set it up this way and try to overload $_config such as ...

```
$_config->__set('NEWDYNAMICITEM', 'SomeDynamicData');
```

and

```
$_config->__get('NEWDYNAMICITEM');
```

Am I going to have a problem because I'm accessing the $_config object by reference due to the dependency container?

Should I just do away with the dependency container all together and just have the DB class extend the config class ?

Or maybe the other way around?

Any help/advice on this would be much appreciated,  I'm trying to set up a custom PHP framework and want to get everything right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing this is confusing.

What works best is injection. In other words, I would skip the overloading entirely and define your database class **outside** your other classes and then inject them into your constructor. That way you only define your database connection once and save overhead.

```
$db = new mysqliObject();
$db->setConfig(depCon::$_config);
$db->connect();
$objct = new exampleObject($db);
```

Comment: This is just the kind of advice I was looking for, thank you, however I am confused on this line.   $db->setConfig(self::$_config);  because setConfig sets the value of $db->_config?  So its like saying  $db->_config = $db->_config?   Can you explain that to me?  Also see my update above explaining what im trying to do in the end.  I may be completely off.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: Good point. It shouldn't be `self` in that case, but the class name. I've corrected that. In your case of storing the config, I would just make a simple array somewhere and pass that into your class for DB credentials

Comment: Won't this spawn a new instance of the DB for every object?  I was trying to just have one instance of the DB and one instance of Config.  Know what I mean?

Comment: No. That's what `static` is for. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Forgive me, I'm just trying to understand this,  sorry if it seems obvious, but ... the way you are showing there, you are creating the object directly through the db class...  however, the static $db property is in the depcon class,  so to me when I do $dbi = depcon::createdatabase,   that is creating a static db object,  however, what your doing doesn't seem static,  can you explain that ?   How it's static when it doesn't have static anywhere in the class and its not being assigned to the depcon static db property?

Comment: My code above should be done **outside** any other classes. So you create `$db` and then inject that into your class.

Comment: So if I'm sending $db as a parameter, it's not being passed by reference,  the receiving class will create a new instance to store that.   (as far as I know) which is the whole reason I was having the dependency container hold teh static object,  so exampleObject() would_construct its' own link to the static db object at depcon::$_db thus using the same object without creating a new instance.   I don't understand how what your doing does that,  do I need to change the way I structure the db class?   Can you post your answer as an edit to your original answer?  That way you have moreroom

Comment: Sorry if I am asking stupid questions or wrong about some of my assumptions,  this is one thing I am fuzzy on so really appreciate you helping me kind of clarify some of this stuff.   :)

Comment: That's not how this works. I won't rehash that here. [Check out this thread for how it works](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/188765/why-are-references-rarely-used-in-php)

Comment: aaaaaah!  I see, I didn't realize that.  I was going about this all wrong.  Thanks for the advice.